# How to scroll a grid up/down in protractor?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, protractor, infinite-scroll, ag-grid

How can I scroll a grid so that I can fetch all element's text for post-processing? Rows under the grid gets created dynamically as I scroll up/down. I tried doing it through Javascript,but, being new to it, did not get success.

I am using protractor and VS Code.

**HTML:**  [image: HTML-Code]

**Tried:**

```
var div = element(by.css('.ag-scrolls'));
var lastRow = element(by.css('CSS value of last visible row in the view e.g: 5th element ')); //I have 5 rows displayed at once in the view. Remaining elements are displayed when I scroll. 
browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].offsetTop;",lastRow.getWebElement()).then(function (offset) {  
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];',div.getWebElement(), offset).then(function() {  
    // assertion of last possible element/row after complete scroll.
    });
});
```

I gave the locator values for first two lines.

Comment: What does "did not get success" mean? Show what you tried, and what result you got. Did you get errors? If so, what errors did you get?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I meant.. I followed few of the posts on similar cases which explained javascript solutions, but couldn't understand the logic behind it. So, trying those codes didn't give me success.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: @BryanOakley, provided the code which I tried.

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Comment: There was no scrolling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162763/discussion-between-niks-and-bryan-oakley).

Answer (score 0):

Use `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", lastRow)`

Answer (score 0):

mouseMove has worked for me. It'll scroll the object you pass to it into view

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(<element>).perform();
```